# CSS correct class selector undestanding

Tags: css, class

Now I have my code  in this way;

CSS:

```
.dhimage{
 width:25px;
 height:25px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
image.className= 'dhimage';
```

What changes if i format CSS like this:

```
.something .dhimage{
 width:25px;
 height:25px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it means, your newly created image has to be inside a container having class `something`, only then the properties of class dhimage will be applied to it. i.e

```
<div class="something" >
   <img class="dhimage" />
</div>
```

if your markup is like above, then only below css will work

```
.something .dhimage
{
   width:25px;
   height:25px; 
}
```

it is called [CSS specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) .

however, if you directly define the css i.e.

```
.dhimage
{
   width:25px;
   height:25px; 
}
```

it will work independent of the parent's CSS.

Now why is it done.

say you have a class name `menu`. but you want the menu class to be different for menus inside the footer of your page and different for the menus inside header of your page,but still you want to keep the name `menu` because you also have certain common rules for all the menus on the site like font-family or whatever. then you can define it as follows:

```
.menu
{
   font-family:'Times';
}
.header .menu
{
  color:Red;
}
.footer .menu
{
  color:Orange;
}
```

and your markup is like

```
<div class="header">
  <ul class="menu">
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <ul class="menu">
  </ul>
</div>
```

your header and footer menu will have different color.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing, really, except for the fact that, in order for the styling from `.dhimage` to be effective, the element containing that class must be inside an element with the class `.something`.